# Global Class to access Variables

Tags: c#

We like to have a global instance of a class and would like to access across the application (in different forms etc)

What are the different possiblities? (other than static class).

Comment: What don't you like about static class?

Comment: To the close voter: this question looks like a real problem that has well-defined solutions. It wasn't asked in any argumentative way. And there is no argumentation at all in the answers. If you think the question is bad for some other reason, please downvote. Close votes are not meant to express that.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern.  Depending on your application you want to be careful though.  You only get one instance of it, and this can cause unexpected behaviors with multiple threads etc. (there are other drawbacks too, my main point is that you have to look at the downsides of the pattern also).

C# patterns: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Answer (score 2):

singleton.

Or perhaps (singletons are frowned upon) you could do something with an IoC.

This generally hints that you're doing something wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use [ASP.NET Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx).

> Application state is a data repository
>   available to all classes in an ASP.NET
>   application. Application state is
>   stored in memory on the server and is
>   faster than storing and retrieving
>   information in a database. Unlike
>   session state, which is specific to a
>   single user session, application state
>   applies to all users and sessions.
>   Therefore, application state is a
>   useful place to store small amounts of
>   often-used data that does not change
>   from one user to another.